# Espresso failed to receive adb test output

Tags: android, jenkins, android-espresso

We have a number of Espresso tests running on our Jenkins machine when pull requests are made, but occasionally we get the following error on any random tests:

> Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Failed to receive adb shell test output within 600000 ms. Test may have timed out, or adb connection to device became unresponsive'. Check device logcat for details

This doesn't happen when we test locally, it appears to only happen on the Jenkins job. How can I prevent the tests from timing out?

Comment: have you tried `adb kill-server; adb start-server` before running the tests?

Comment: @Shark I have not, but I'll look around Jenkins and see if there's an option to do that. I can add gradle task build steps, but idk if I can get it to run the adb command. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your test. 
If you are using spoon framework with Espresso max time limit per test execution is 10 min. 
If your test take more then 10 min you will get this error.

Two ways to resolve this issue. 
1. you can break your test and reduce its execution time 
2. change timeout limit

use

--adb-timeout       Set maximum execution time per test in seconds (10min default)

reference : https://github.com/square/spoon